# how to change copyright field website level to store level

Tags: magento-1.8, scope, copyright

I have multiple website and multiple store configuration where I need to set different copyright text for each store.

I checked the `system->configuration->general->design->footer`

Their is a copyright field but this scope is website level, so I can set one copyright text to one website not for each store.

How Can I do this, Is their any other way to do this?

Or

**How to change the scope of Copyright field from website level to store level,** That is easy to show different Copyright content to different store.

Suggest any idea,
Thanks for your time,:)

Answer (score 3):

You can set Copyright Field for each store view,

[image]